# Themes in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-styles

Hola ***Stackoverflowers***!

i have like 10 fragments in the navigation drawer.. however i want one fragment to have a special theme, and i want the activity itself and the other fragment have the same theme. 
How can i achieve that?

**What i tried:**

```
        ctx = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),
        R.style.myappstyletimes);
                LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(ctx);
        View view = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.prayerpager, container,
        false);         View view = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.prayerpager, container,
            false);
return view;
```

And i also changed the context of my app to ctx... it's still the same theme presented in the manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/maintheme" >
```

My Theme:

```
    <style name="myappstyletimes" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle.Transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentcolor</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-developers/126dgb5swc/how-apply-a-theme-in-a-fragment#201206134b2upqqlep77qkjzqur7zptrru)?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Yes it did not work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, i think i just might have an answer for you. In using the code you have:

```
ctx = new ContextThemWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.myappstyletimes);
LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(ctx);
View view = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.prayerpager, container, false);
return view;
```

You have to set up a custom theme that you make, as demonstrated below

```
<style name="myappstyletimes" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

This changes the background to `black` and the text to `white`.

I tested this myself, and it works.

**Edit:**
Here are some tutorials on custom themes:

[DeveloperLife](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=309)

[Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html)

[Android Coding](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/01/create-custom-theme-inheriting.html)

Comment: @Fringo What is your theme structure?

Comment: and the `<style ... > </style>` around the `<item ...> </item>`s?

Comment: @Fringo try amending the `<style parent="android:Theme.Material">` to `<style parent="android:style/Theme.Material">`

Comment: same results :/ any idea?

Comment: No, i'm sorry. This worked for me and hoped it would help you.